# Did Swami Vivekananda speak about his enlightenment?

Tags: vivekananda, enlightenment

I want to know if Swamiji himself ever spoke about his enlightenment.

Did he or anyone talk about his enlightenment? I heard that he was more into social service and freedom movement.

Comment: You're asking too many things in one questions.  Instead you should focus on a single question in each post.

Comment: so should i make multiple threads ?? if it okay ?

Comment: Yeah, make multiple threads.

Comment: Yes, he did. Not in public but to a few people. He did not go about advertising it. There are instances in his Complete Works where he talks of it as well as in some of the writings of his gurubhais.

Comment: can someone please quote

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda welcome to Answer the question :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this quotation mentions it:

> Whenever death approaches me, all weakness vanishes. I have neither fear, nor doubt, nor thought of the external. I simply busy myself making ready to die. I am as hard as that [the pebbles struck one another in his hand] — for I HAVE TOUCHED THE FEET OF GOD !" (CWSV 1: 262)