# Did Swami Vivekananda ever claim he was self-realized?

Tags: vivekananda

Did Swami Vivekananda ever claim he was self-realized?

Please cite from his works or conversations.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17236/did-swami-vivekananda-speak-about-his-enlightenment

Comment: @Rickross No one has answered that.

Comment: That I can see without u telling me .. but I guess still urs is a dupe..